# While sending mails in PHP, unwanted symbols like = and 3D are appearing at the receiver's end

Tags: php, email, bugzilla

While Trying to send mails in PHP, I could see that unwanted symbols like "=" and "3D" are appearing in the content.

This is the to header portion of the mail.

```
From: 
Reply-To: 
To: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

I am posting some examples of the issue:

1)original content:

```
=============
```

At the receiver's end, it become:

```
=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3
```

2)Original content:

```
Algeria
```

Receiver's end:

```
Alger=
ia
```

Can anybody help me to find the exact issue or has anybody experienced similar issues

Comment: Have you cut&pasted any of the email's text from a Windows program, particularly something like Microsoft Word? They're infamous for mangling plaintext into other forms that don't play nicely with other programs/encodings.

Comment: Post your code...maybe there's something wrong there.

Comment: @Marc, No I haven't done anything of that type. The mail recepient had informed about this issue

Comment: Are you passing the message through some filtering function before passing it to the mail() function? can you share the code?

Answer (score 4):

That's perfectly normal quoted-printable encoding. Perhaps you forget to mention in the headers that the message is encoded in quoted-printable.

Comment: I have mentioned about encoding also. Is there any issue with MIME version?                                                         From: 
Reply-To: 
To: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue some time ago. I think it turned out if the line you send as your body is too long, you can run into problems. I was using the [phpmailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) library. I used

> $mail->Encoding='base64';

to get around the problem. I was sending html emails though, not plain text.

I don't know what PHP version you are using, but check out if '[magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)' could be causing your problem.